# Compute the order of each of the elements in $D_6$ where $D_{6}=\left\langle r, s \mid r^{3}=s^{2}=1, r s=s r^{-1}\right\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation, dihedral-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

> Compute the order of each of the elements in $D_6$ where $D_{6}=\left\langle r, s \mid r^{3}=s^{2}=1, r s=s r^{-1}\right\rangle$

I found six elements of $D_6$ are $1,r, r^2,s, rs, r^2s.$

**How can I show that there is no element other than $1,r, r^2,s, rs, r^2s$?**

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yess. Thanks. I got $sr=r^2s$.

Comment: You are welcome. This is much better.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I edited the question. Now, the question is more logical, can you help?

Comment: We are already done now, because we know that $sr=r^2s$.

Answer (score 2):

For the order of $rs$ we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
(rs)^2&=&rsrs\\
&=&sr^{-1}rs\\
&=&s^2\\
&=&1
\end{eqnarray*}

Similarly for $r^2s$.

Comment: to know who is $sr$ do: $sr=srs^2=srss=ssr^{-1}s=r^2s$